# Inexplicable behavior in WebGL shader on iOS

Tags: ios, glsl, webgl, regl

I'm seeing some strange behavior that I can't explain in a WebGL shader I've written. This is not an area of expertise for me, so it's entirely possible that I'm misunderstanding something pretty simple, but I'm not sure what.

I have a codepen illustrating the strange behavior here https://codepen.io/bjvanminnen/pen/XqMpvL.

```
void main () {
    vec3 color = vec3(0.);

    vec2 loc1 = vec2(0.5, 0.) / u_res;
    vec2 loc2 = vec2(1.5, 0.) / u_res;
    float val1 = texture2D(u_tex, loc1).r * 255.;
    float val2 = texture2D(u_tex, loc1).r * 255.;
    color.r = val1 == val2 ? 1. : 0.;
    // commenting/uncommenting this line somehow affects the b value
    // on iOS, when uncommented we end up with (53, 0, 255, 255)
    // when commented we end up with (255, 0, 0, 255)
    // I can think of no reason why the below line should affect color.b
    color.r = floor(val1) / 255.;

    color.b = val1 == 53. ? 1. : 0.;      
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.);
}
```

A summary of what's happening

- In JS, I create a texture where each pixel is #350000
- In my fragment shader, read the first two pixels
- Initially set the r value of the output to be 1 if the two pixels are identical (they should be)
- When uncommented, change the value of color.r based on the floor of val1 (a step that I would not expect to affect color.b)
- Set the b value of the output to be 1 if the pixel value is 53 (i.e. 0x35).
- I then examine the resulting pixel values in JS.

My expectations:
When the second `color.r` line is commented out, I would expect a result of (53, 0, 255, 255). This IS what I see on my desktop, but on my iOS device I see (53, 0, 0, 255). It appears to be the case that val1 ends up being slightly larger than 53 on iOS. I'm assuming this is just floating point weirdness.

What's super strange and I can't understand is that when I comment out the second `color.r` line, I get (255, 0, 255, 255) on my desktop - which makes sense - but (255, 0, 0, 255) on my iOS device.

**In other words the presence/non-presence of the line `color.r = floor(val1) / 255.;` is somehow changing the result of `color.b`.**

Have I encountered some strange iOS bug, or am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking in the [GLSL ES 1.0 spec](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf) there's a bunch of sections on invariance starting at section 4.6

The important part for your case is probably 4.6.2

> ## 4.6.2 Invariance Within Shaders
>
> When a value is stored in a variable, it is usually assumed it will remain constant unless explicitly
>   changed. However, during the process of optimization, it is possible that the compiler may choose to
>   recompute a value rather than store it in a register. Since the precision of operations is not completely
>   specified (e.g. a low precision operation may be done at medium or high precision), it would be possible
>   for the recomputed value to be different from the original value.
>
> Values are allowed to be variant within a shader. To prevent this, the invariant qualifier or invariant
>   pragma must be used.
>
> Within a shader, there is no invariance for values generated by different non-constant expressions, even if
>   those expressions are identical.
>
> Example 1:
>
> ```
> precision mediump;
> vec4 col;
> vec2 a = ...
> ...
> col = texture2D(tex, a); // a has a value a1
> ...
> col = texture2D(tex, a); // a has a value a2 where possibly a1 ≠ a2
> ```
>
> To enforce invariance in this example use:
>
> ```
> #pragma STDGL invariant(all)
> ```
>
> Example 2:
>
> ```
> vec2 m = ...;
> vec2 n = ...;
> vec2 a = m + n;
> vec2 b = m + n; // a and b are not guaranteed to be exactly equal
> ```
>
> There is no mechanism to enforce invariance between a and b.

You're comparing a float to an exact value which seems dangerous in pretty much any language. If I change this line

```
color.b = val1 == 53. ? 1. : 0.;
```

to

```
color.b = val1 > 52.9 && val1 < 53.1 ? 1. : 0.;
```

Then it works as expected for me. Also, if I write out `val1` with

```
color.g = val1 / 153.;
```

I don't see it change. It's 88 whether or not that line is commented out even though your test fails. That suggests to me it's not 53.0 in one case. It's 53.000000000001 or 52.9999999999999 etc...

Comment: Thank you! That's very interesting to learn regarding shader invariance. Adding the pragma got me to a point where I'm not getting that unexpected behavior.